# Need help in analyzing the graph

Tags: unetstack

For a 2 node network, I've written an agent named "sensor" which sends a datagram req from node A to node B continuously for 5 mintues with a delay of 10 seconds between every datagram. After simulation, with the generated trace.json file i am trying to plot the graph for the rtt of each datagram.

```
import json as js
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open('trace1.json',"r")
data = f.read()
obj = js.loads(data)
list1 = obj['events']
flag = False
bias = 0

for j in range(len(list1)):
    eventobj = list1[j]
    list2 = eventobj['events']
    Dict = {}
    timeList = []
    T = 0
    R = 0
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        if(flag == False):
            bias = list2[0].get('time')
        st = list2[i].get("stimulus")
        if(st['sender'] == 'phy' and st['recipient'] == 'phy'):
            if st['messageID'] in Dict:
                if "response" in list2[i]:                       
                    res = list2[i].get("response")
                    if(res['clazz'] != 'org.arl.unet.phy.BadFrameNtf' and res['clazz'] == 'org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf'):
                        time1 = Dict[st['messageID']]
                        
                        time2 = list2[i].get("time")
                        diff = abs(time1 - time2)
                        timeList.append([(time1 - bias)/1000,diff/1000])
                        R = R+1
            else:
                if "response" in list2[i]:
                    res = list2[i].get("response")
                    if (res['clazz'] == 'org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameNtf' and st['clazz'] == 'org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem$TX'):
                        Dict[st['messageID']]=(list2[i].get("time"))
                        T = T+1
print(timeList)

x = []
y = []

for i in timeList:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,400)
plt.ylim(0.8,1.2)
plt.xlabel('Timeline in seconds')
plt.ylabel('delay in seconds')

plt.show()
```

And the graph looks like this:
[image: graph]

By observing the graph, I am not able to understand that within in a simple 2 node network why there such delay variation can be seen for every alternate datagram?(And why for every alternate datagram the delay is less?)

Comment: Few queries-Why not have `else` in `if(flag == False):  bias = list2[0].get('time')`? What's the use of counters `R` & `T`? On `y-axis` are you plotting `RTT` (Round-Trip Time) or `delay`? Is the `x-axis` limit `(0,400)` correct? why `abs(diff = abs(time1 - time2)`? For plotting, you can use `x = [(i[0] - bias) / 1000 for i in timeList]
y = [i[1] / 1000 for i in timeList]`, only if it works for you

Comment: Is this simulated using the `RealTimePlatform` or the `DiscreteEventPlatform`? What did your code for transmitting every 10 seconds look like?